# How to tell which event triggered a workflow from inside the workflow?

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio, workflow-activity, events

I have a SharePoint 2013 workflow created in VisualStudio (not Designer).

Originally this workflow only ran on `ItemAdded`, but now I need it to also run on `ItemUpdated`.

Is there a way to tell from within the workflow which event triggered that instance?

I see the `LookupWorkflowContextProperties` activity, but that only allows you to check

- Associator
- Initiator
- Association Name
- Instance ID
- Current Site URL
- Current Item URL
- List Name
- List Id

with nothing about the triggering event.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value of `WorkflowSubscritpionEventType` enum in your code.

According to below documentation, It will return `1` for `ItemAdded` and `2` for `ItemUpdated` trigger.

```
public enum WorkflowSubscritpionEventType
{
    None = 0,
    ItemAdded = 1,
    ItemUpdated = 2,
    ItemDeleted = 4
}
```

**Source**: [GitHub - WorkflowProvisionService.cs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Property-Inspection-Code-Sample/blob/master/PropertyManagerMyApp/PropertyManagerMyApp/Services/WorkflowProvisionService.cs).

Comment: Do you know which workflow activity exposes that value?  In building the workflow in VS, I'm not writing code per se, but using the workflow designer to build the workflow using "activities" that are in the `Microsoft.SharePoint.DesignTime.Activities` or `Microsoft.Activites` namespaces.  I need to be able to determine the trigger even using those provided tools.